# Error scoped and unscoped bigquery issue

Tags: google-bigquery

```
SELECT
MAX(IF(customDimensions.index=1, customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN hits 
AS CustomerID,
date as date
SUM(totals.visits) Visits,
EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(fullvisitorid) AS Users,
FROM [xxxxxxx.ga_sessions_xxxxx] 
Group by CustomerID;
```

I am getting the following error when i run the above query "Error: Invalid mixture of scoped and unscoped aggregation functions". Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck the "Use Legacy SQL" box under "Show Options"), you should be able to construct a query such as:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT MAX(IF(index=1, value, NULL))
   FROM UNNEST(customDimensions)) AS CustomerID,
  date as date,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS Visits,
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullvisitorid) AS Users
FROM `xxxxxxx.ga_sessions_xxxxx`
GROUP BY CustomerID, date;
```

Here is an example query to illustrate the approach:

```
WITH SampleTable AS (
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>
      [(5, "foo"), (1, "bar"), (1, "baz")] AS customDimensions,
    "20160518" AS date,
    STRUCT(10 AS visits) AS totals,
    "visitorid" AS fullvisitorid
  UNION ALL SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>
      [(0, "foo"), (4, "bar"), (2, "baz")] AS customDimensions,
    "20160519" AS date,
    STRUCT(20 AS visits) AS totals,
    "visitorid" AS fullvisitorid)
SELECT
  (SELECT MAX(IF(index=1, value, NULL))
   FROM UNNEST(customDimensions)) AS CustomerID,
  date as date,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS Visits,
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullvisitorid) AS Users
FROM SampleTable
GROUP BY CustomerID, date;
+------------+----------+--------+-------+
| CustomerID |   date   | Visits | Users |
+------------+----------+--------+-------+
| baz        | 20160518 |     10 |     1 |
| NULL       | 20160519 |     20 |     1 |
+------------+----------+--------+-------+
```

Alternatively, I think you'll need a subquery to compute the max over the `customDimensions` repeated field using legacy SQL:

```
SELECT
  CustomerID,
  date as date,
  SUM(totals.visits) Visits,
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(fullvisitorid) AS Users
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(IF(customDimensions.index=1, customDimensions.value, NULL))
      WITHIN customDimensions AS CustomerID
  FROM [xxxxxxx.ga_sessions_xxxxx])
GROUP BY CustomerID, date;
```

Comment: Can you explain what went wrong? I had to guess at what your table's schema is for the query that I provided, but I may have made an invalid assumption.

Comment: i am getting this - Error: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword FROM at [7:1]

Comment: Ah, looks like I had a trailing comma after `AS Users` (I updated the answer). Can you see if this works? If it still doesn't, can you share the schema that you are working with?

Comment: I am getting this error now -> Error: Cannot access field index on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>. 

I am basically using the GA data that was exported into BQ.

Comment: I was confused by the use of hits in your query; is there a reason that you used WITHIN hits? I updated my answer to operate on customDimensions in the subquery instead, so please see if this works.

Comment: it works and this is exactly what i need but is it possible to convert this query to use  Legacy SQL? I am currently building a complicated query to export my data and it is using  Legacy SQL.

Comment: Sure, I updated my response with a legacy SQL query as well.